# What is the better way to store an arbitrary key:value array in mongodb

Tags: schema, mongodb

I have an array of key values

{val1:
   [{gender:male}, {age:23}, {favorite-color:red}]
}

The thing about this array is that in no way is it structured and in no way am I ever guaranteed to see the same key value again.  For example I could see the following for val2

{val2:
   [{sex:male}, {hair-color:red}, {height:6'1"}]
}

My question is whether is is better to have each of these keys as a column in mongo, or should I keep them in an array?  I know with mongodb it is possible to create an arbitrarily large number of columns so either way would theoretically work.  If I wanted to query if an array contained the key of 'sex' with a value of 'male', would that be possible in the example where I keep the values in a nested array in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's `valX` for anyways? I would just use regular "columns."

```
john : { gender:"male", age:23, favorite-color:red }
bob : { gender:"male", age:25, favorite-color:blue }
susan : { gender:"female", age:20, favorite-color:yellow }
```

You can search for against the 3 fields using basic queries.

Comment: valx will be quite arbitrary.  The thing is that gender, age, or any other property may not be in any other of the records.  So wondering if it still makes sense to make it a column even if it may only be used once.

Comment: Um, that's what's good about not having a schema per say. Each record doesn't have to match the record below or above it. You say gender, age, and others may not be in any other records. That's perfect. So you can still store it for a record. If you query for let's say "gender is male," you'll only get results where the record has a gender value of male.